# Determinant of $B=I_n+A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Supposing that $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $A^{3}=0$, where $\det A=0$, how can I prove that the determinant of the matrix $B =I_{n} +A$ is nonzero?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Actually I see that when I write martix A in reduced echelon form and add I_n to it it becomes nonsingular, so the determinant of the matrix becomes nonzero; however, I did not manage to do the same thing to the matrix A, in its original form. I think I am missing something related to A³=0.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Expand
$$
(I+A)(I-A+A^2)=\ldots
$$
What then can you infer from this?

**Bonus**: See if you can repeat the exercise to show that $I-A$ is also invertible.

**Bonus 2**: Here is another way to look at this. Suppose that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $v\neq 0$ is a corresponding eigenvector. Then: $A^3v=\lambda^3v$. Can $\lambda\neq 0$? In particular, can $\lambda=-1$? How do the eigenvalues of $I+A$ relate to the eigenvalues of $A$? In fact, using this approach, you can go beyond showing $\det(I+A)\neq 0$: you in fact can compute $\det(I+A)$ precisely.

Comment: Thank you so much, by defining I_n-A+A² as C, I had a chance to determine, whether it is zero or not, the determinant of B.